# How can I append to an existing record?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a column in a schema called `notes`. It contains revision notes that are supposed to be updated each time a record is updated. How do you append data to the existing entry without overwriting?

For example, currently it shows:

> "09022014, Updated user's GSDA ID."

After I run my query, I want to see:

> "09022014, Updated user's GSDA ID. 04062015, Updated TTFIA building
>   field."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate (||) the new note with the current note:

```
update tablename set notes = notes || " new note"
where id = 123;
```

Oh and don't forget the regular expression:

```
update tablename set notes = 
regexp_replace('notes', '^(.*)$', '\1' || ' note 2')
where id = 123;
```

This brought to light an unexpected result using regexp_replace, which I asked about here in case you are interested: [Explain unexpected regexp_replace result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473269/explain-unexpected-regexp-replace-result)

Answer (score 1):

**Concatenate** the existing column value with the new value using the **concatenation operator** `||`.

> "09022014, Updated user's GSDA ID. 04062015, Updated TTFIA building field."

If you have the double-quotation marks along with the value itself, then there is an additional thing you need to take care of, i.e. **TRIM** the **double-quotation marks** in the right of the existing column value.

And, of course, you need to keep a space between the existing value and the new value.

For example,

```
UPDATE table_name 
   SET notes = rtrim(notes, '"') || ' ' || new_note || '"';
```